# Schema for users that can "activate" others, that in turn can activate others

Tags: postgresql, schema

This is my first question ever so sorry if it's not up to standards.

I have a problem with figuring out solution for an interesting requirement:

A user on a system has their own url that when shared redirects people to signup.

http://site.com/activators/user_id_hash-username

This way we can track which users "activate" other users.

It's simple so far.

The problem starts with a requirement of being able to count activations beyond the first degree of separation i.e. **let the user get credit for users activated by users SHE initially activated**.

I'm not sure what the schema should look like for this.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Is relational DB a good fit for this?
When I'm trying to think of a query for this my brain gives up...

We're using PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you need to recursively track activators, you will need a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE).

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe. So simply storing "Activations" on one table with references to user "userId" and using recursive query would be efficient once table gets very large?

Comment: With the proper indexes, yes.